# Is $2^{218!} +1$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove that $2^{218!} +1$ is not a prime number.

I can prove that the last digit of this number is $7$, and that's all.

Thank you.

Comment: What I love in elementary number theory questions is that you can tweak parameters so easily to make it computationally infeasible; but the proofs, once you know the method, are about the same.

Comment: [See the theorem here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers): $2^n+1$ prime implies $n=2^k$. Such primes are called Fermat primes. Interestingly, it is not knwon whether there are infinitely many Fermat primes, and the only ones known are $F_0,F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$, where $F_k=2^{2^k}+1$.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

$$218!=3n:\;\;\;2^{218!}+1=(2^{n}+1)(4^{n}-2^{n}+1)$$

Answer (score 53):

Well, $a^3+1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)$, so it's not prime, and we have
$$2^{218!}=(2^{2\cdot4\cdot5\cdot..\cdot 218})^3\,.$$

Comment: Everybody took the $3$ out, but it also works with any odd exponent, as in general $a+1\,|\,a^m+1$ if $m$ is odd.

Answer (score 13):

$x=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \dots 218$

$2^{218!}+1 =2^{3x}+1=(2^{x}+1)(2^{2x}-2^{x}+1)$

Comment: I think you want the $+1$ out the exponent there, since the left side is odd.

Comment: Oh, cruel math world. One typo and a 5 seconds late of proof delivery costs 400 karma.

Comment: @igf Don't worry about it too much, Stack Exchange sites cap you at a maximum of 200 rep gain per day.

Answer (score 7):

Another one: $2^{2^{213}}+1\mid2^{218!}+1$ because $218!=2^{213}\cdot k$ with $k$ odd.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\: k\:$ is odd then $\rm\:a^n\!+\!1\mid a^{nk}\!+\!1\ $ by $\rm\ mod\ a^n\!+\!1\!:\ a^n\!\equiv -1\:\Rightarrow\:a^{nk}\!\equiv (a^n)^k\!\equiv (-1)^k\equiv -1.\:$

**Or** $ $ Factor Theorem $\rm\:\Rightarrow\: x\!-\!c\mid x^k\!-\!c^k\: $ in $\rm\:\Bbb Z[x],\:$ so $\rm\:c=-1\:\Rightarrow\: x\!+\!1\mid x^k\!+\!1,\:$ hence evaluating at $\rm\:x = a^n\:$   yields $\rm\:a^n\!+\!1\mid a^{nk}\!+\!1\:$ in $\,\Bbb Z.\:$ Thus this *integer* divisibility results is a special case of a *polynomial* divisibility result. Factors of this form are sometimes called *algebraic factors*.

Similar to the example above, often *number* identities are more perceptively viewed as special cases of *function* or polynomial identities. $ $ For example, $ $ [Aurifeuille, Le Lasseur and Lucas](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.548) $ $ discovered so-called [**Aurifeuillian factorizations**](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2006-75-253/S0025-5718-05-01766-7/S0025-5718-05-01766-7.pdf) of cyclotomic polynomials $\rm\;\Phi_n(x)\, =\, C_n(x)^2\! - n\, x\,  D_n(x)^2\;$. These play a role in factoring integers of the form $\rm\; b^n \pm 1\:$, cf. the [Cunningham Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_project). Below are some simple examples of such factorizations.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\rm x^4 + 2^2 &=\,&\rm  (x^2 + 2x + 2)\;(x^2 - 2x + 2) \\\\
\rm \frac{x^6 + 3^3}{x^2 + 3} &=\,&\rm  (x^2 + 3x + 3)\;(x^2 - 3x + 3) \\\\
\rm \frac{x^{10} - 5^5}{x^2 - 5} &=\,&\rm  (x^4 + 5x^3 + 15x^2 + 25x + 25)\;(x^4 - 5x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 25) \\\\
\rm \frac{x^{12} + 6^6}{x^4 + 36} &=\,&\rm  (x^4 + 6x^3 + 18x^2 + 36x + 36)\;(x^4 - 6x^3 + 18x^2 - 36x + 36) \\\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

For more on this and related topics see Sam Wagstaff's  [introduction to the Cunningham Project.](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun1.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

In general, we the following to be true.

**Claim**:

If $a^n+1$ is a prime, then $n = 2^k$. To put it the other way around: If $n = 2^k \cdot m$, where $m$ is odd and greater than $1$, $a^n+1$ is composite.

**Proof**:

Let $k$ be the highest power of $2$ such that $2^k \vert n$, i.e., $2^k \Vert n$. We then have $n = 2^k \cdot m$, where $m$ is odd. Hence, we have
$$a^n+1 = a^{2^k \cdot m} + 1 = \left(a^{2^k}\right)^m + 1$$
Now we have
$$b + 1 \vert b^m+1$$whenever $m$ is odd. Hence, we have $$a^{2^k}+1 \vert \left(a^{2^k}\right)^m + 1 \implies a^{2^k}+1 \vert a^n+1$$ Hence, if $m \neq 1$, we have $a^n+1 > a^{2^k}+1$ and $a^{2^k}+1 \vert a^n+1$. Hence, if $m \neq 1$, we get that $a^n+1$ is not a prime. This forces $m$ to $1$. Hence, if $a^n+1$ is a prime, then $n = 2^k$.

---

In your case, take $a=2$ and $n = 218!$ and clearly (Why?) $218! \neq 2^k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Hence, $2^{218!}+1$ is not a prime.

Answer (score 1):

$$218! \equiv 0 \mod \left( \left\{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,...,217!! \right\}\right)$$

> $$\left(2^{\frac {218!}{2k+1}} \right)^{2k+1}+1 \equiv 0 \left(\mod 2^{\frac {218!}{2k+1}}+1 \right)$$, where $k≤\frac {217!!+1}{2} .$